# Split number in javascript to display after and before decimal number in different font size

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex, split

I have a plan page to show to my customer which 3 plans for my Website product - Basic , Premium and VIP with all plans having monthly and yearly price.

I get the following value from backend for `$products` for USA and India where this product is available only in these 2 countries. So based on the country selected, I display the prices for my customer

Products returned for USA:

```
$products = [
          {
            monthly_price => "\$5.95”,
            yearly_price => "\$40.95",
            type => "basic"
          },
          {
            monthly_price => "\$10.95”,
            yearly_price => "\$80.95",
            type => "premium"
          },
          {
            monthly_price => "\$15.95”,
            yearly_price => "\$120.95",
            type => "vip"
          },
]
```

Products returned for IND:

```
$products = [
          {
            monthly_price => "\₹200.55",
            yearly_price => "\₹2500.55”,
            type => "basic"
          },
          {
            monthly_price => "\₹400.55",
            yearly_price => "\₹5000.55”,
            type => "premium"
          },
          {
            monthly_price => "\₹800.55",
            yearly_price => "\₹1000.55”,
            type => "vip"
          },
        ];
```

Following is the CSS file:

```
.main-price {
   font-size: 45px;
}

.decimal-price {
   font-size: 15px;
}

.term {
   font-size: 15px;
}
```

Main and decimal price has different CSS where I have used the class below. So I split after the dot (.) which will be 2 values. So I do it as .1 and .2

Following is the HTML file:

```
[% FOR price in products -%]
    [% monthly_price = price.monthly_price.split('.') %]
    [% yearly_price = price.yearly_price.split('.') %]
    <h1>[% price.type.uc %]</h1>
    <p>
        <span class="main-price">[% monthly_price.1 %]</span>
        <span class="decimal-price">[% monthly_price.2 %]</span>
        <span class="term">per month</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="main-price">[% yearly_price.1 %]</span>
        <span class="decimal-price">[% yearly_price.2 %]</span>
        <span class="term">per year</span>
    </p>
[%- END %]
```

I tried the following 3 different solutions also , but it dint work:

- Solution 1:

```
[% monthly_price.1 %]
```

- Solution 2:

```
[% monthly_price[0] %]
```

- Solution 3:

```
[% monthly_price.first %]
```

Expected:

- I want to display main price in 45px font size and decimal price/term in 15px font size.

Issue:

- Main price and decimal price is not getting displayed

Can anyone please help where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: out of curiousity, may I ask what programming language you're using on that code? That looks more like a templating engine, right ?, it feels like a mixing of both javascript and templating engine

Comment: First check after split what're you getting in monthly price variable once..

Comment: I am getting products from Perl programming language

Comment: I am getting blank value after split. Before split, i get the right value

Comment: Yes, it's a template engine and javascript, you are absolutely right Duc Hong

Comment: Any idea @Duc Hong ?

Comment: Any idea @Prabhat ?

Comment: @SaAshTechs I checked in javascript I'm able to split by ('.') but your code is not pure javascript so, I don't aware of this kind of coding.

Comment: I second that idea, you should double check on template engine documentation to make sure they have a `.split` method or some what identical `splitting` method to turn a string into an array, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm checking in javascript. It's working fine. But your code is not pure javascript. So, I don't aware of this kind of code.

Check there split() support or not.

```html
<script>
var products = [
          {
            monthly_price : "\$5.95",
            yearly_price : "\$40.95",
            type : "basic"
          },
          {
            monthly_price : "\$10.95",
            yearly_price : "\$80.95",
            type : "premium"
          },
          {
            monthly_price : "\$15.95",
            yearly_price : "\$120.95",
            type : "vip"
          },
]
products.forEach(price => {
  var res=price.monthly_price.split('.');
  console.log(res[0]);
  console.log(res[1]);
});
</script>
```